# Possible mistake in statement of a condition in Smullyan and Fitting when proving the well-ordering of $g$-towers

Tags: set-theory

Context: self-study of Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* (rev ed. 2010) chapter $4$, section $\S 3$, "The well ordering of $g$-towers".

> Every $g$-tower is well ordered under inclusion. More specifically, if $M$ is a $g$-tower, then $M$ is linearly ordered under inclusion and for any non-empty subclass $A$ of $M$, if $L$ is the set of all elements $x$ that are proper subsets of all elements of $A$, then the following three conditions hold:

> (1) If $L$ is empty, then $\varnothing$ is the least element of $A$

> (2) If $L$ is non-empty and contains a greatest element $x$, then $g(x)$ is the least element of $A$.

> (3) If $L$ is non-empty and contains no greatest element, then $\cup L$ (the union of $L$) is the least element of $A$.

(EDIT: Clarification of what a $g$-tower is, as apparently it is not a standard term: a **$g$-tower** is a class which is minimally superinductive under a progressing mapping $g$.)

The clause I have trouble with is:

> ... if $L$ is the set of all elements $x$ that are proper subsets of all elements of $A$, then ...

Does this mean:

- $\{x \in M: \forall z \in A: x \subset z\}$

or does it mean:

- $\{x \in M: \exists z \in A: x \subset z\}$

I believe what is actually meant is the second one, but from the way it's worded, it appears actually to look as though it means the first one. "the set of *all* elements $x$ (of $A$, presumably) that are proper subsets of **all** elements of $A$.

But that would mean $\{x\}$ would be a singleton, and $x$ would actually be (by the structure of $M$, it's a $g$-tower and so is superinductive under $g$) the smallest element of $A$.

Am I misinterpreting this? Is there a "standard" reading of this which is unambiguous, and I've just failed to interpret it correctly?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I could have: I've read your entire question and I still have no idea what a "g-tower" is. (It's not a standard term.) The phrase you're puzzled by surely doesn't mean the first alternative: if $L = \{x \in A: \forall z \in A: x \subsetneq z\}$ then $L = \emptyset$, as $x\in L \rightarrow x \subsetneq x$.

Comment: @BrianO The last time I posted a comment requesting that notation / terminology be explained, I was told "If you need to be told what it means, then you're obviously not knowledgeable enough to answer the question", so ever since I have been careful not to include too much information. Seems you can never get it right on this site. I'm getting utterly fed up with it.

Comment: @BrianO ... but a closer reading suggests the domain of $f$ is actually $M$ and not $A$, which makes it more sensible. S&F are not as precise as perhaps they ought to be. A $g$-tower is a class which is minimally superinductive under a progressing mapping $g$.

Comment: @BrianO Sorry, domain of $g$ not $f$.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Whoever you previously interacted with seems to be (1) under the very mistaken impression that one must be familiar with terminology in advance in order to answer a question, or (2) too full of themselves to spend the brief time it would take to provide clarification, or (3) an @$$hole. Sadly, you'll run into such people.... I tend to err on the side of providing more information in my questions than I think will be needed, but on the other hand, I don't generally ask other questioners for more information than they've given. I wish I had better guidance for you than that!

Comment: @KurtG. See the comments under this question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/the-assumption-of-knowledge-of-what-notation-means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $\{x\in M\mid \forall z\in A, x\subset z\}$. $L$ is the set of all (strict) lower bounds for $A$.

Comment: So basically S&F *are* correct. I have been coming to this conclusion by pondering it closely. Your answer confirms what I thought.